# Comparo dos Strings y no me entra en el IF

Tags: java, string, netbeans

```
System.out.println("Dime el tablero al que te quieres conectar :");

tablero = sc.nextLine(); // AQUI LO LEO COMO UN STRING EN EL CLIENTE

tablero = tablero.trim();

byte buffer_tablero[];

buffer_tablero = tablero.getBytes();

DatagramPacket mensaje_tablero = new DatagramPacket(buffer_tablero, buffer_tablero.length, InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 50000);


puerto.send(mensaje_tablero); // Aqui envio el mensaje con el numero de tablero al que me quiero conectar


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

puerto.receive(tablero);
buffer = tablero.getData();
datos = new String(buffer, buffer.length); // AQUI PASO A STRING LO QUE RECIBO DEL PAQUETE

System.out.println("He recibido una peticion para el tablero " + datos);

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if (datos.equals("1") || datos.equals("2") || datos.equals("3")) {}
```

En este if no me entra enviando desde el cliente alguno de estos 3 valores. Debugueando miro el valor de la variable y tiene el mismo valor, cuando llega al if no entra.

Comment: por que no evaluas tablero == "1"?

Comment: Si no pones un println dentro de las llaves del if ¿Como sabes si entra o no?

Comment: Este codigo esta simplificado, dentro del if hay mucho codigo, que haciendo debug no entra ni hace nada. solo que salta al else de ese if como si no coincidiera.

Comment: datos cuando hago debug tiene un valor de "1" y luego no entra

Comment: escribiendo un codigo simple, por ejemplo `String datos = "1";` y ocupar tu mismo IF si funciona, por lo tanto el error esta por otro lado, ahora, si el usuario escogio el tablero mediante el teclado, por que en el if no comparas por el dato que tomaste por entrada?

Comment: ¿El valor que lleva `datos` no podría llevar espacios en blanco?

Comment: antes de pasarselo, hago un .trim() por si acaso.

Comment: sioesi he puesto justo antes del if `datos = "1" ` y si que entra en el if pero la cuestion que el valor de la variable si que el mismo y no entra. Porque puede ser?

Comment: ¿La variable `datos` es `String` o `char`?

Comment: la variable de datos es un `String`

Comment: Si sirve, de ayuda, he probado a hacer un `Integer.parseInt(datos)`y salta la exception de `NumberFormatException` y en realidad es porque tiene algun espacio pero luego lo que es el valor de la variable la muestro por pantalla y sale sin espacios.

Comment: que tipo de dato es `tablero` ? porque el metodo getData() para hacer el buffer no es de tipo String

Comment: La primera parte del codigo es del cliente, la segunda y el if es del servidor. y al hacer `tablero.getData()` `tablero` es es de tipo `DatagramPacket`

Comment: @RubenGilGomez Debuguea en el if que valor tiene datos?

Comment: `datos` tiene valor de datos="1"

Comment: Recomiendo usar algo como `System.out.printf("Cadena: \"%s\"\n", datos);` para ver el contenido de tu cadena. Quizás se esté pasando un caracter adicional. El hecho de agruparlo entre comillas ayudará a ver esto. Para un mejor análisis, te recomiendo copiar la salida de la consola a un editor de texto y convertir el texto en hexadecimal para ver si realmente es la información que quieres enviar.

Comment: La respuesta esta abajo, datos tenia espacios en la parte del servidor despues de recibir el paquete. Un saludo y gracias a todos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la variable `datos` es de tipo `String` aunque sea un objeto (`new String()`), es difícil que no cumpla la sentencia, posiblemente tu variable `datos` contenga espacio(s):

```
if (datos.trim().equals("1") || datos.trim().equals("2") || datos.trim().equals("3")) {
...
...
```

Comment: Funciona asi, gracias, hacia el `.trim()` en el cliente antes de enviar pero no lo hacia a la hora de recibir. Un error de principiante.

Answer (score 0):

En java lo mejor es utilizar la funcion *equals* cuando es un string dentro del if.

**Pero Espera**

Para estar completamente seguro de lo que vas a comparar si es un String, como buena **practica de programación** es mejor que compares de la siguiente forma.

```
if (("1".equals(datos)) || ("2".equals(datos)) || ("3".equals(datos))) {}
```

Ahora por que digo que para estar completamente seguro de que es un **String**, por que si compara el dato que te envian con el string a comparar. El dato que te envian puede que venga como **null**, si ves. En tu caso si comparas asi:

```
if ((datos.equals("1")) || (datos.equals("2")) || (datos.equals("3"))) {}
```

Puede que la variable datos venga como null entonces de una vez la condición no se cumple.

**Ahora si hace como yo te digo, estas completamente seguro de que los que vas a comparar es un string con cualquier otra cosa que se supone que debe ser un string.**

Saludos