# ¿porque no puedo comparar al usar if?

Tags: java

Hace muy poco empece a usar `JAVA` para crear aplicaciones con `Android Studio`, he estado intentando hacer una aplicación que envié un mensaje si es correcto o incorrecto la letra que ingrese el usuario ( letras ya guardadas en variables ) 
En este caso la letra correcta es "a" pero al momento de poner el código me marca que los operadores no van así, alguien sabe como resolverlo ?
Me marca este error:

> error: incomparable types: EditText and String

```
public class CuartoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



EditText txt1;
EditText txt2;
EditText txt3;
EditText txt4;
EditText txt5;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cuarto);
    txt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    txt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    txt3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt3);
    txt4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt4);
    txt5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt5);
    String resultado1 = "a";


    if (txt1 == resultado1){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Correcto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (txt1 != resultado1){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Podrías por favor añadir que error exactamente te sale?

Comment: Disculpa, el error es error: incomparable types: EditText and String. ya agergue el error a la publicacion.

Comment: El error hace referencia a un problema con lo que estan almacenando ambas variables, mientras que `resultado1` es un caracter, ¿qué valor almacena `txt1`?

Comment: Pues si no me equivoque al escribir el codigo, lo puse para resultado1 almacene el caracter "a" mientras que txt1 se el valor que el usuario ingresa, y de ahi ya hace la comparacion

Answer (score 5):

Debes primeramente saber las siguientes consideraciones:

1) Para obtener el texto dentro de un [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText) debes usar los métodos:

```
.getText().toString();
```

Ejemplo:

```
myEditText.getText().toString();
```

2) La comparación de cadenas de caracteres se realiza mediante el método [.equals()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38996/comparo-dos-strings-y-no-me-entra-en-el-if/39189#39189) y además puedes hacer uso del método .trim() para eliminar espacios en los extremos de la cadena.

---

De acuerdo a lo anterior la forma correcta de realizar la comparación de acuerdo a tu código sería:

```
if (txt1.getText().toString().equals(resultado1)){ //Es igual.
    Toast.makeText(this, "Correcto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else if (!txt1.getText().toString().equals(resultado1)){ //Es diferente.
    Toast.makeText(this, "Incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

lo cual podría ser reducido simplemente a:

```
if (txt1.getText().toString().equals(resultado1)){ //Es igual.
    Toast.makeText(this, "Correcto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else { //Es diferente.
    Toast.makeText(this, "Incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas comparando un `objeto` de tipo `EditText` con un `objeto` de tipo `string`.
Tienes que obtener el `string` de tu `EditText` y compararlo, asi:

```
if (txt1.getText().toString() == resultado1){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Correcto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (txt1.getText().toString()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```